# Nested multivalue field

Tags: java, nested, multivalue, magnolia

These three fields are part of multivalue field, but I need to make the field Business Groups a multivalue field as well, which should save its values as a list. See my configuration

[image]

[image]

But the problem is that I can't save the values and I get exception

[image]

Is that possible to create nested multifield?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment. But should be in few weeks once 5.2.5 version is released. See [MGNLUI-2871](http://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-2871) for details.